# Equal Height Columns with display: table. width

Tags: html, css

trying to find out why columns are different width, and how to make them equal width.

```css
.col-container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.col {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-container">
  <div class="col col1">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col col2">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col col3">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some other text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: they have same width

Comment: in other words , how to spread them evenly ....

Comment: if you will inspect by right clicking on these columns you will notice that most right column is always wider than first and second.
column first is 203px 
column second: 204px
third column: 215px;

Comment: and what about the answer below, does this answer and fixes your trouble ? each cells have the same width ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `table-layout:fixed;` property, it should **spray  the columns evenly**(*question keyword :* **equal width**).

You can also add a `width` to secure it . `border-spacing` should be included within the `width` calculation if you also uses it.

> https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#propdef-table-layout
>
> 17.5.2.1 **Fixed** table layout
>
> With this (fast) algorithm, the horizontal layout of the table does not depend on the contents of the cells; it only depends on the table's width, the width of the columns, and borders or cell spacing.

```css
.col-container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.col {
  display: table-cell;
  border: solid;
}

.w {
  margin-top: 1em;
  border-spacing: 2px;
}
/* add width and border-spacing */
.w.col {
  width: 33.33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-container">
  <div class="col col1">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col col2">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col col3">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some other text.. Some other text.. Some other text.. Some other text..</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-container w">
  <div class="col col1">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col col2">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col col3">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some other text.. Some other text.. Some other text.. v Some other text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Downvote?, explain why and where i missunderstood the question, thank you

Comment: I didnt downvote, i upvoted, its fixed by adding to container table-layout:fixed. thanks alot